# Converting .print file to STL

Tags: stl, grabcad-print

Hi I am trying to obtain the STL for the automatically generated support structure for a part that has been 3D printed, is there any way of doing this from the GrabCAD .print file? Or any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1):

STL files represent solid objects as triangles covering a surface.

Most support structures are not solid objects, but thin walls whose size depends on the diameter of your nozzle, and in some cases, calling them walls is generous.

Support structure is usually generated at the slicer level, which generates images of layers or gcode tool paths, and it does not make sense to translate that back into an STL.

Comment: however, one *can* do so, in fact, prusaslicer allows to export with the support structure - usually this is used to offer presupported STLs for resin models.